# Displaying ASP script errors in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

A classic ASP script is generating an error and displaying 500 - Internal server error.

In IIS7 Under ASP Features->Debuging Properties I have enabled "Send Errors to Browser"

What am I missing  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Internet Explorer, go to

> Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced

and disable

> "Show friendly HTTP Errors"

Comment: Thanks, but it was already set to "Show friendly HTTP Errors".

Comment: Also, the same problem occurs with Chrome

Comment: Sorry. "disable". Right, it's working now !!